# Parsing pipe delimited input in awk

Tags: parsing, awk, pipe, delimited

Have seen many posts asking similar question.  Can't get it working.

Input looks like:

```
<field one with spaces>|<field two with spaces>
```

Trying to parse with awk.

Have tried many variants from excellent posts:

```
FS = "^[\x00- ]*|[\x00- ]*[|][\x00- ]*|[\x00- ]*$";
FS = "^[\x00- ]*|[\x00- ]*\|[\x00- ]*|[\x00- ]*$";
FS = "^[\x00- ]*|[\x00- ]*\\|[\x00- ]*|[\x00- ]*$";
```

Still can't get the pipe delimiter to work.

Using CentOS.

Any help?

Answer (score 14):

```
 echo "field one has spaces | field two has spaces" \
 | awk '
   BEGIN {
      FS="|" 
 }
 {
   print $2
   print $1
   # or what ever you want
 }'

 #output

  field two has spaces
  field one has spaces
```

You can also reduce this to

```
awk -F'|' {
    print $2
    print $1
}'
```

**Edit**
Also, not all awks can take a multi-character regex for the `FS` value.

**Edit2**
Somehow I missed this originally, but I see you are trying to include `\x00` in the char classes pre and post of the `|` char. I assume you mean for `\x00` == `null` char? I don't think you're going to be able to have `awk` parse a file with null chars embedded. You could prep-rocess your input like

```
 tr '\x00'   ' ' < file.txt > spacesForNulls.txt
```

OR delete them altogether with

```
tr -d '\x00' < file.txt > deletedNulls.txt
```

and eliminate that part of your regex. But as above, some `awk` don't support regex for the `FS` value. *And, I don't use the `tr` trick very much, you may find that it requires a slightly different notation for the `null` char, depending on your version of `tr`.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great point with `\x00`. Or the op should use a more specialized tool like `perl` or `ruby`. ++

Comment: `I don't think you're going to be able to have awk parse a file with null chars embedded` Or a second thought? `awk '{gsub("\x00","")}1` is possible.